# Forms, basic calculator key triggering problem

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

```
 private void UserInputText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyCode == Keys.D4 && e.Modifiers == Keys.Shift) || (e.KeyCode == Keys.Add))
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInputText.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Bir sayı giriniz.");
                UserInputText.Clear();
                return;
            }
            if (double.TryParse(UserInputText.Text, out sayı1))
            {
                CalculationResultText.Text = sayı1 + " + ";
                islem = "+";
                UserInputText.Clear();
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Sadece sayı değeri girebilirsiniz.");
                UserInputText.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I am coding a basic forms calculator. I am trying to trigger addition function and clear the textbox when textbox is focused and user presses "+" key.  "`if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInputText.Text))` and `else` conditions work well. But if no Message boxes shows up as in the
`if (double.TryParse(UserInputText.Text, out sayı1))` condition, the "+" character remains in the textbox as in the image. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to first check the character that was typed in and if it's incorrect then you want to prevent this character from appearing?

If so, then you need to set `e.Handled = true` property when you want to prevent it.

This call tells the GUI element (your `TextBox`) that "I did all the checks for this event (i.e. `KeyDown` event), and I don't want you to contribute in handling of this event (i.e. normally the `TextBox` would try to add this character to its `Text` property, but you prevent it)".

Check out documentation on [`KeyEventArgs.Handled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Prevention works well. Simply, i want to clear the textbox after                                          "if (double.TryParse(UserInputText.Text, out sayı1))" condition is met. But whatever reason "+" character remains in the textbox only after this condition is met.

Comment: @CoderT did you put `e.Handled()` after `UserInputText.Clear();`?

Comment: I think i need to learn more coding. But putting exactly `e.Handled()` after `UserInputText.Clear();` it gives me 
"CS1955 Non-invocable member 'KeyEventArgs.Handled' cannot be used like a method. "       error. Thanks for help.

Comment: When i put `MessageBox.Show("Lorem Ipsum");` after `islem = "+";`  it works pretty well. But i dont want to put any message boxes there.

Comment: @CoderT Oh wait it's my bad, `e.Handled` is a property, so it should be `e.Handled = true`, I've confused it

Comment: `e.Handled = true;` doesnt do anything different for me.

Comment: @CoderT try also `e.SuppressKeyPress = true;`

Answer (score 0):

`KeyPress` event enables you to prevent any further changes in the TextBox.
You can do that thanks to `Handled` property of `KeyPressEventArgs`

```
private void UserInputText_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '+')
    {
        UserInputText.Clear();      
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `KeyChar` can't be used like this and `e.Handled = true;` doesnt do anything different.